# Как запретить выполнение конвертора после получения необходимого значения?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Добрый, имею привязанную коллекцию `List` к `ListBox`. В коллекции содержатся значения, которые надо перевести по следующей логике:

- Получаем с сервера JSON.
- Сохраняем его и находим необходимое значение в файле.
- Если значение найдено, то выводим его, если нет - выводим исходное значение.

Я все это реализовал с помощью `IValueConverter`, который задается с помощью привязки. Но вот в чем проблема! Так, как коллекция обновляется раз в 1 минуту и значений там штук 8, то получается как минимум 8 раз загружает JSON файл (это еще без подключенного чтения файла с сервера...).

Мне в таком случае необходимо запретить выполнение конвертирования, если значение было уже переведено. Пробовал по [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956703) принципу (то есть задаем переменную и в нее заносим значение, если переменная не пуста - выводим ее, не выполняя всю логику), но этот вариант у меня не работает, просто запоминает первое значение и постоянно его переводит.

**Собственно вопрос:** Как запретить выполнение конвертации больше 1 раза?

---

**Сам код текущего конвертора:**

```
class PlanetConvert : IValueConverter
    {
        private string _item;
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (_item != null) return _item;

            string[] planet;
            Debug.WriteLine($"Переводим значение {value}!", $"[{DateTime.Now}]");
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader($"{Settings.Program.Directories.Data}/Filters/Planets.json"))
                {
                    var json = r.ReadToEnd();
                    var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                    planet = System.Convert.ToString(data["Items"].First[value]).Split('|');
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e);
                return value;
            }

            if (parameter != null && parameter.ToString() == "Sector" && planet.Length >= 2)
            {
                _item = planet[1].ToUpper();
                return _item;
            }
            if (parameter != null && parameter.ToString() == "Planet" && planet.Length >= 2)
            {
                _item = planet[0].ToUpper();
                return _item;
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }
```

**Привязка:**

```
<Run Text="{Binding MissionInfo.Location, ConverterParameter=Planet, Converter={StaticResource PlanetConvert}}" />
```

Comment: Почему такие операции выполняются в конвертере, а не в модели представления?

Comment: @Vlad: Через "get;set;" имеете ввиду? Если да, то там ведь тоже получится множественное чтение, при каждом обновление коллекции.

Comment: Вы же все равно качаете все файлы с сервера. Я не пойму, какие именно операции вас смущают? Просто конвертер, на мой взгляд, крайне неудачное место для операций с вводом-выводом.

Comment: @Vlad: Если использовать данный код, то он открывает каждый раз JSON файл, ищет в нем значение и отдает. Можете [вот](https://i.imgur.com/y8W5mNv.png) посмотреть лог того, сколько раз он выполнил перевод. То есть он в данном случае 10 раз открыл файл и выдал значение (это я только часть необходимых данных перевел), к тому же у меня раз в 1 минуту происходит чтение других данных с сервера, которые обновляют эту коллекцию и даже старые данные он переводит заново.

Comment: @Vlad: А если подключить к этому загрузку последнего файла фильтров (JSON) с сервера (ибо они периодически обновляются), то не хило так запросов будет идти к серверу каждую минуту. Их конечно можно отдельно проверять и обновлять скажем раз в 5 мин (фоном), но все равно. Чтение по много раз файл JSON это как то много. Если писать там, где вы говорите - мне кажется будет тот же эффект.

Comment: Ну вот вам нужно обновить коллекцию. Вы взяли исходные данные коллекции (то, что нужно найти в файле), скачали JSON, переписали коллекцию найденными значениями, сохранили JSON на диск (если надо). В итоге в вашей коллекции постоянно будут сами данные, а не "ссылки" на них. И операций чтения не так много выходит.

Comment: Хм, обдумал сейчас все это. То есть мне лучше создать некую функцию, которая будет вызываться после добавление основных данных. Данная функция 1 раз откроет нужный JSON файл, затем циклом обновит все необходимые значения и закроет файл. Хорошо, снизит количество чтений, но опять же, он ведь будет постоянно читать этот файл, даже если нету новых значений в коллекции. Хотя у меня есть эвент, который определяет, новое значение или нет. Может на него подписать эту функцию...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Vlad прав, это не задача для конвертера, это задача для бизнес-логики.

Comment: @VladD: Ну мне получается надо циклом пройтись по уже добавленным элементам, или как то по другому это реализуется?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Ну, например так. Можно применять какие-то трюки с `HashSet`, но это уже улучшение и оптимизация. Сначала напишите простой вариант с обходом в цикле.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, читайте файл при изменении коллекции. Тем более, если у вас уже есть место, где на изменение можно подписаться.